# How do I create an ordered list (HTML/CSS) with different background images for different entries?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've got this navbar menu set up, with a multilayer background so that color changes on hovered and current tabs. However, the color scheme for what I have so far is mostly green, and within the same list, I want to make the next 'block' of tabs blue, and a third block red. I have more images ready to multilayer and stuff, but I can't seem to get the darn thing to override the background for each li entry, since the main thing is coded on the ol itself. It's only actually loading the image on "ol#vin a {" and "ol#vin span {"; the rest of the options (hover, current, etc.) only change the background position so my multi-layered image translates down to the appropriate state.

If it helps, I based it on this: http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=bonus where he's got the tabbed list, but I have it going vertical down the left side with my own background.

E: As requested, code snippets:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr valign="top">
<td width="260px">
    <ol id="vin">
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-aaaa"><span>Section A</span></a></li>
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-bbbb"><span>Section B</span></a></li>
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-cccc"><span>Section C</span></a></li>
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-dddd"><span>Section D</span></a></li>
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-eeee"><span>Section E</span></a></li>
        <li class="au"><a href="#sc-ffff"><span>Section F</span></a></li>
    </ol>
</td><td style="background:#ccc">
    <div class="content" id="sc-aaaa">
        <h2>Section A</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sc-bbbb">
        <h2>Section B</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sc-cccc">
        <h2>Section C</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sc-dddd">
        <h2>Section D</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sc-eeee">
        <h2>Section E</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sc-ffff">
        <h2>Section F</h2>
          Content goes here!
    </div>
</td></tr></table>
activatables('section', ['sc-aaaa', 'sc-bbbb', 'sc-cccc', 'sc-dddd', 'sc-eeee', 'sc-ffff']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
ol#vin {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ol#vin li {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

ol#vin a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ol #vin #au a {background: url(vtabs.png) no-repeat;}
ol #vin #ma a {background: url(vtabs2.png) no-repeat;}

ol#vin a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -52px;
    color: #000;
}

ol#vin a:hover span {
    background-position: 100% -52px;
}

ol#vin li a.active {
    background-position: 0 -26px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol#vin li a.active span {
    background-position: 100% -26px;
}

ol#vin span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

ol#vin #au span {background: url(vtabs2.png) 100% 0;}
ol#vin #ma span {background: url(vtabs2m.png) 100% 0;}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample markup and css so we can see what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to define specific IDs or class for the elements, then you can specify the background image for each ID or class.

### Original

From the linked sample: http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=bonus

```
<ol id="toc">
    <li><a href="#introduction" class=" inactive"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#step-1" class=" inactive"><span>Step 1: The structure</span></a></li>
    <!-- more ... -->
</ol>
```

### Solution

#### HTML

```
<ol id="toc">
    <li id="first_li"><a href="#introduction" class=" inactive"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
    <li id="second_li"><a href="#step-1" class=" inactive"><span>Step 1: The structure</span></a></li>
    <!-- more ... -->
</ol>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Usual states */
#toc li#first_li {
    background-image: url('/img/first_background.jpg');
}

#toc li#second_li {
    background-image: url('/img/second_background.jpg');
}

/* Hover states */
#toc li#first_li:hover {
    background-image: url('/img/first_background_highlight.jpg');
}

#toc li#second_li:hover {
    background-image: url('/img/second_background_highlight.jpg');
}
```

Comment: May require a more specific rule than the one you mentioned or an `!important`.

Comment: Of course you can use `background-color: #ff0000;`, `background-color: #0000ff;` etc. instead of images, too.

Comment: Smamatti, that didn't work; I moved just the background stuff into "ol#vin #au a {" + "ol#vin #ma a {" and "ol#vin #au span {" + "ol#vin #ma span {" and it didn't load the backgrounds at all. I'm'a edit the post and include my HTML and CSS real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you will achieve it only using a JavaScript solution, because the CSS specification doesn't allow you to style parent elements. An example using jQuery:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li data-color="#00f"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li data-color="#0f0"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li data-color="#f00"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the script:

```
var $nav = $("#nav");
$nav.find("li").hover(function () {
    $nav.css("backgroundColor", $(this).attr("data-color"));
}, function () {
    $nav.css("backgroundColor", "");
});
```

Comment: Why do you think, that this requires Javascript/jQuery? You are actually editing the CSS via script. This will not work for deactivated scripts, needs more performance and is possibly less barrier-free. In addition custom attribute like `data-color` are not valid HTML.

Comment: `data-` attribues are valid HTML 5.

Comment: Agreed. But in this case it's still XHTML 1.0

Comment: Smamatti, we are talking about a 1ms operation. People who have JS deactivated will use the site normally, but without the full background hover.